# Using fonts with html

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a font, Indie Flower, which I'm trying to use in my site. I've followed what Google told me:

Copy and pasted this into my `head`tag:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then i specified my css like so:

```
.event {
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-size:80px;
border: none;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
text-align: center;
}
```

So why isn't it displaying?

Comment: If it's live site share your site url over here

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. You aren't showing your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space in your link. Remove the space and make sure your white font color is not causing issues with you seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using white as a text color that rgba(255,255,255,0.6) means white color with opacity of 0.6. for black color you have to put rgba(0,0,0,0.6).

## This is working code

I hope it helped you.

```css
.name {
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-size:30px;
border: none;
color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='name'>
  Muhammad Muzammil
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Leave that just see that i have solved your issue. I am a blogger user so that's why its my regular practice.

Answer (score -1):

The link is wrong. Check this. I got this correct link and it's working fine.

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
    <p id="p1">this is the indie flower text </p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
#p1{
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```